# Java 8 + Swing: How to Draw Flush Polygons

Tags: java, swing, polygon

(Sorry for the long post... at least it has pictures?)

I have written an algorithm that creates a mosaic from an image by statistically generating *N* convex polygons that cover the image with no overlap.  These polygons have anywhere between 3-8 sides, and each side has an angle that is a multiple of 45 degrees.  These polygons are stored internally as a rectangle with displacements for each corner.  Below is an image that explains how this works:

[image]

`getRight()` returns `x + width - 1`, and `getBottom()` returns `y + height - 1`.  The class is designed to maintain a tight bounding box around filled pixels so the coordinates shown in this image are correct.  Note that `width >= ul + ur + 1`, `width >= ll + lr + 1`, `height >= ul + ll + 1`, and `height >= ur + ul + 1`, or there would be empty pixels on a side.  Note also that it is possible for a corner's displacement to be 0, thus indicating all pixels are filled in that corner.  This enables this representation to store 3-8 sided convex polygons, each of whose sides are at least one pixel in length.

While it's nice to mathematically represent these regions, I want to draw them so I can see them.  Using a simple lambda and a method that iterates over each pixel in the polygon, I can render the image perfectly.  As an example, below is [Claude Monet's *Woman with a Parasol*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woman_with_a_Parasol_-_Madame_Monet_and_Her_Son) using 99 polygons allowing all split directions.

[image]

The code that renders this image looks like this:

```
public void drawOnto(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.setColor(getColor());
    forEach(
        (i, j) -> {
            graphics.fillRect(x + i, y + j, 1, 1);
        }
    );
}

private void forEach(PerPixel algorithm) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        int nj = height - 1 - j;

        int minX;
        if (j < ul) {
            minX = ul - j;
        } else if (nj < ll) {
            minX = ll - nj;
        } else {
            minX = 0;
        }

        int maxX = width;
        if (j < ur) {
            maxX -= ur - j;
        } else if (nj < lr) {
            maxX -= lr - nj;
        }

        for (int i = minX; i < maxX; ++i) {
            algorithm.perform(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is not ideal for many reasons.  First, the concept of graphically representing a polygon is now part of the class itself; it is better to allow other classes whose focus is to represent these polygons.  Second, this entails many, many calls to `fillRect()` to draw a single pixel.  Finally, I want to be able to develop other methods of rendering these polygons than drawing them as-is (for example, [performing weighted interpolation over the Voronoi tessellation represented by the polygons' centers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947842/weighted-interpolation-over-triangle)).

All of these point to generating a `java.awt.Polygon` that represents the vertices of the polygon (which I named `Region` to differentiate from the `Polygon` class).  No problem; I wrote a method to generate a `Polygon` that has the corners above with no duplicates to handle the cases that a displacement is 0 or that a side has only one pixel on it:

```
public Polygon getPolygon() {
    int[] xes = {
        x + ul,
        getRight() - ur,
        getRight(),
        getRight(),
        getRight() - lr,
        x + ll,
        x,
        x
    };
    int[] yes = {
        y,
        y,
        y + ur,
        getBottom() - lr,
        getBottom(),
        getBottom(),
        getBottom() - ll,
        y + ul
    };

    int[] keptXes = new int[8];
    int[] keptYes = new int[8];
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (
            length == 0 ||
            keptXes[length - 1] != xes[i] ||
            keptYes[length - 1] != yes[i]
        ) {
            keptXes[length] = xes[i];
            keptYes[length] = yes[i];
            length++;
        }
    }

    return new Polygon(keptXes, keptYes, length);
}
```

The problem is that, when I try to use such a `Polygon` with the `Graphics.fillPolygon()` method, it does not fill all of the pixels!  Below is the same mosaic rendered with this different method:

[image]

So I have a few related questions about this behavior:

1. Why does the `Polygon` class not fill in all these pixels, even though the angles are simple multiples of 45 degrees?
2. How can I consistently code around this defect (as far as my application is concerned) in my renderers so that I can use my `getPolygon()` method as-is?  I do not want to change the vertices it outputs because I need them to be precise for center-of-mass calculations.

---

**MCE**

If the above code snippets and pictures are not enough to help explain the problem, I have added a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example that demonstrates the behavior I described above.

```
package com.sadakatsu.mce;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {
    @FunctionalInterface
    private static interface PerPixel {
        void perform(int x, int y);
    }

    private static class Region {
        private int height;
        private int ll;
        private int lr;
        private int width;
        private int ul;
        private int ur;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Region(
            int x,
            int y,
            int width,
            int height,
            int ul,
            int ur,
            int ll,
            int lr
        ) {
            if (
                width < 0 || width <= ll + lr || width <= ul + ur ||
                height < 0 || height <= ul + ll || height <= ur + lr ||
                ul < 0 ||
                ur < 0 ||
                ll < 0 ||
                lr < 0
            ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            this.height = height;
            this.ll = ll;
            this.lr = lr;
            this.width = width;
            this.ul = ul;
            this.ur = ur;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return Color.BLACK;
        }

        public int getBottom() {
            return y + height - 1;
        }

        public int getRight() {
            return x + width - 1;
        }

        public Polygon getPolygon() {
            int[] xes = {
                x + ul,
                getRight() - ur,
                getRight(),
                getRight(),
                getRight() - lr,
                x + ll,
                x,
                x
            };
            int[] yes = {
                y,
                y,
                y + ur,
                getBottom() - lr,
                getBottom(),
                getBottom(),
                getBottom() - ll,
                y + ul
            };

            int[] keptXes = new int[8];
            int[] keptYes = new int[8];
            int length = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                if (
                    length == 0 ||
                    keptXes[length - 1] != xes[i] ||
                    keptYes[length - 1] != yes[i]
                ) {
                    keptXes[length] = xes[i];
                    keptYes[length] = yes[i];
                    length++;
                }
            }

            return new Polygon(keptXes, keptYes, length);
        }

        public void drawOnto(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(getColor());
            forEach(
                (i, j) -> {
                    graphics.fillRect(x + i, y + j, 1, 1);
                }
            );
        }

        private void forEach(PerPixel algorithm) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
                int nj = height - 1 - j;

                int minX;
                if (j < ul) {
                    minX = ul - j;
                } else if (nj < ll) {
                    minX = ll - nj;
                } else {
                    minX = 0;
                }

                int maxX = width;
                if (j < ur) {
                    maxX -= ur - j;
                } else if (nj < lr) {
                    maxX -= lr - nj;
                }

                for (int i = minX; i < maxX; ++i) {
                    algorithm.perform(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int width = 10;
        int height = 8;

        Region region = new Region(0, 0, 10, 8, 2, 3, 4, 1);

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            width,
            height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR
        );
        Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        region.drawOnto(graphics);
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("expected.png"));

        image = new BufferedImage(
            width,
            height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR
        );
        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.fillPolygon(region.getPolygon());
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("got.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the coolest thing I've seen all day :-) +1

Comment: This looks to me as if the definition of the interior of the polygon in *your* code differs from that of java.awt.Polygon; both are correct within *their* frame of reference, theyre just different definitions. You will need to transform from your definition to Polygon's; no way around that if you want to use Polygon...

Comment: @Durandal: That is true.  My issue is that I have not yet found an explanation as to how this approach works.  If I can learn the rhyme and reason to explain why sometimes it generates the same results and other times it does not, I will be able to make progress.  So far, I have not found this explanation.

Comment: @peeskillet: :) I will put this application, Mosaic, up on my GitHub (https://github.com/sadakatsu) when it is completely usable.  You can play around with it once it's up.  I'm hoping that will be in 1-2 weeks.

Comment: overide getPreferredSIze for JPanel, then all coordinates are from getHeight/weight incl. repainting on resize (forgot for pixels perfect, e.g. to divide 10 by 3:-), all block are only shapes, put all Object to the Array, inside paintCOmponent to loop inside array of Object, here are a few code examples about

Comment: @mKorbel: I do not understand your comment.  What does it have to do with my question?

Comment: `when I try to use such a Polygon with the Graphics.fillPolygon() method, it does not fill all of the pixels`, If I understand the problem then try using both fillPolygon() and drawPolygon(). The drawPolygon should fill in the outline of the Polygon.

Comment: @camickr: I have tried that, but it does not always work.  I am trying to determine what all the cases are that cause this, but an example is a 1-point "polygon", which does not draw in either `drawPolygon()` or `fillPolygon()`.

Comment: @sadakatsu 1. without an SSCCE/MCVE this question isn't answerable, looks like as here isn't interest to give lessons from algebra 2. What does it have to do with my question? - here are a few attempts JPanel with Objects stored in array in JScrollPane and are zoomable (in-out e.g. honeycomb is there 2-3 times)

Comment: @mKorbel, 1. I have added an MCVE per your request (though, frankly, I think doing so is unnecessary; the text, code, and images cover everything pertaining to my problem). 2. Again, you are proposing a "solution" that has nothing to do with my question.  I am asking about the behavior of rendering `java.awt.Polygon`.  I know all about iterating through collections of items to perform the same algorithm on each, and I said nothing at all about wanting to be able to zoom.  Your comments are completely off-topic, and I cannot fathom why you think that they are relevant.

Comment: @peeskillet: I have posted a very initial release of my Mosaic application at https://github.com/sadakatsu/Mosaic .  Feel free to check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent all day working on it, and I seem to have a fix for this.  The clue was found in the documentation for the [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) class, which reads:

> **Definition of insideness**: A point is considered to lie inside a Shape if and only if:
>
> - it lies completely inside theShape boundary or
> - it lies exactly on the Shape boundary and the space immediately adjacent to the point in the increasing X direction is entirely inside the boundary or
> - it lies exactly on a horizontal boundary segment and the space immediately adjacent to the point in the increasing Y direction is inside the boundary.

Actually, this text is a bit misleading; the third case overrides second (i.e., even if a pixel in a horizontal boundary segment on the bottom of a `Shape` has a filled point to its right, it still will not be filled).  Represented pictorially, the `Polygon` below will not draw the *x*'ed out pixels:

[image]

The red, green, and blue pixels are part of the `Polygon`; the rest are not.  The blue pixels fall under the first case, the green pixels fall under the second case, and the red pixels fall under the third case.  Note that all of the rightmost and lowest pixels along the convex hull are NOT drawn.  To get them to be drawn, you have to move the vertices to the orange pixels as shown to make a new rightmost/bottom-most portion of the convex hull.

The easiest way to do this is to use camickr's method: use both `fillPolygon()` and `drawPolygon()`.  At least in the case of my 45-degree-multiple-edged convex hulls, `drawPolygon()` draws the lines to the vertices exactly (and probably for other cases as well), and thus will fill the pixels that `fillPolygon()` misses.  However, neither `fillPolygon()` nor `drawPolygon()` will draw a single-pixel `Polygon`, so one has to code a special case to handle that.

The actual solution I developed in trying to understand the *insideness* definition above was to create a different `Polygon` with the modified corners as shown in the picture.  It has the benefit (?) of calling the drawing library only once and automatically handles the special case.  It probably is not actually optimal, but here is the code I used for anyone's consideration:

```
package com.sadakatsu.mosaic.renderer;

import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.sadakatsu.mosaic.Region;

public class RegionPolygon extends Polygon {
    public RegionPolygon(Region region) {
        int bottom = region.getBottom();
        int ll = region.getLL();
        int lr = region.getLR();
        int right = region.getRight();
        int ul = region.getUL();
        int ur = region.getUR();
        int x = region.getX();
        int y = region.getY();

        int[] xes = {
            x + ul,
            right - ur + 1,
            right + 1,
            right + 1,
            right - lr,
            x + ll + 1,
            x,
            x
        };

        int[] yes = {
            y,
            y,
            y + ur,
            bottom - lr,
            bottom + 1,
            bottom + 1,
            bottom - ll,
            y + ul
        };

        npoints = 0;
        xpoints = new int[xes.length];
        ypoints = new int[xes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < xes.length; ++i) {
            if (
                i == 0 ||
                xpoints[npoints - 1] != xes[i] ||
                ypoints[npoints - 1] != yes[i]
            ) {
                addPoint(xes[i], yes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```